# Calculate time elapsed using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate time elapsed since my birthday in the form of (years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds) using JavaScript.

For example, my birth date is 15-Oct-1989, 00 hrs 00 mins 00 secs. Hence, time elapsed since my birth date is,

```
22 years 5 months 10 days 19 hours 25 minutes 25 seconds
```

I want to achieve the same output using JavaScript code. Any link or so will certainly help in this case.

Comment: You need two javascript Date objects:  one that represents the current date and one that represents your birth date.  Then you need to write code to build that string by comparing the two objects.

Comment: yes i have implemented the part where i can calculate hours, mins & secs. Guess that was the easier part becoz i m struggling to calculate days & months.

Answer (score 12):

Try something like this:

```
var now = new Date();
var bDay = new Date(1989, 10, 15);
var elapsedT = now - bDay; // in ms
```

Read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for further info. That'll give you some idea how to format the result.

Comment: Forgot to mention... If you don't like dealing with JS Date API, check out http://momentjs.com/ . That library contains some sensible default ops.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I needed `var elapsedT = now - bDay` instead

Comment: @nishantjr Thanks, tweaked.

Answer (score 10):

Since my previous answer has people missing the point entirely, here's a port of PHP code I have to do the same thing:

```js
    function getDaysInMonth(month,year) {     
        if( typeof year == "undefined") year = 1999; // any non-leap-year works as default     
        var currmon = new Date(year,month),     
            nextmon = new Date(year,month+1);
        return Math.floor((nextmon.getTime()-currmon.getTime())/(24*3600*1000));
    } 
    function getDateTimeSince(target) { // target should be a Date object
        var now = new Date(), diff, yd, md, dd, hd, nd, sd, out = [];
        diff = Math.floor(now.getTime()-target.getTime()/1000);
        yd = target.getFullYear()-now.getFullYear();
        md = target.getMonth()-now.getMonth();
        dd = target.getDate()-now.getDate();
        hd = target.getHours()-now.getHours();
        nd = target.getMinutes()-now.getMinutes();
        sd = target.getSeconds()-now.getSeconds();
        if( md < 0) {yd--; md += 12;}
        if( dd < 0) {
            md--;
            dd += getDaysInMonth(now.getMonth()-1,now.getFullYear());
        }
        if( hd < 0) {dd--; hd += 24;}
        if( md < 0) {hd--; md += 60;}
        if( sd < 0) {md--; sd += 60;}

        if( yd > 0) out.push( yd+" year"+(yd == 1 ? "" : "s"));
        if( md > 0) out.push( md+" month"+(md == 1 ? "" : "s"));
        if( dd > 0) out.push( dd+" day"+(dd == 1 ? "" : "s"));
        if( hd > 0) out.push( hd+" hour"+(hd == 1 ? "" : "s"));
        if( nd > 0) out.push( nd+" minute"+(nd == 1 ? "" : "s"));
        if( sd > 0) out.push( sd+" second"+(sd == 1 ? "" : "s"));
        return out.join(" ");
    }

// Example:

console.log(getDateTimeSince(new Date(1992,1,6,22,30,00)));
```

my date of birth - near enough half past ten in the evening on Feb 6th 1992

> 20 years 1 month 18 days 17 hours 23 minutes 7 seconds

I believe this is *exactly* what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Thanks for this code.. this is a good start. For anyone else that may use this, I had to reverse the order of the subtractions. Also, unless my logic has late-night flaws, I think the order of the conditional carry operations should be reversed too (with least significant time-spans first). Lastly, diff wasn't used at all.. not sure why that's there. Anyway, great contribution!

Answer (score 7):

First of all, what you demand is a bit imprecise. We know that a minute = 60 seconds, a hour = 60 minutes... And it stops here. A day can be either 24 or just a little more than 24 hours, depending how you treat leap years, and "one month" doesn't even try to represent a time span precisely.

Hence: Either keep your timespans as hours, or establish an approximation to deal with leap years etc. **Dates and date differences (timespans) are different concepts** and need to always be treated differently.

Anyway, as for the code, I'd simply go for :

```
var ms = new Date() - yourBirthDate;
var secs = ms/1000;

var minutes = secs    / 60 ;  secs    = secs    % 60;
var hours   = minutes / 60 ;  minutes = minutes % 60;
// and so on if you want
```

Comment: You are right!! but i believe this is what the challenge is !

Comment: The challenge is to formulate your problem in a way that can be answered. :) The precise answer to a "how long question" (if you're after precision) can only be expressed in SI units of time, or their multiples like hours or days (but not solar days). If you're after months, you can only say i.e. how many months have started since then. When I say I'm 23 years old, then I only mean that I've hit my birthday date so many times, I don't mean a precise timespan.

Answer (score 3):

Use Moment.js for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates in Javascript. Only 5.5k so not much of a good reason to do this kind of low-level code yourself these days.

http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).  Specifically, on that page, look for the "Calculate Elapsed Time" section (near the bottom):

```
// using static methods
var start = Date.now();
// the event you'd like to time goes here:
doSomethingForALongTime();
var end = Date.now();
var elapsed = end - start; // time in milliseconds
```

In your case, the `start` would be a given date:

```
var start = new Date(1989,10,15);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate to the number of days, or even weeks, you can do this just by subtracting the current timestamp from your birthday's timestamp and divide the number into its component time units.

However if you want months and years, it's a bit more complicated due to the variable number of days in a month.

Perhaps the easiest way to go about it is as follows:

1. Get the difference in years (currentYear - birthYear)
2. Get the difference in months (currentMonth - birthMonth)
3. Repeat for all units
4. If any unit is negative, subtract 1 from the unit above and add however many of the current unit make up the bigger unit.

The complication arises when you want to find how many days are in a given month. This can help:

```
function getDaysInMonth(month,year) {
    if( typeof year == "undefined") year = 1999; // any non-leap-year works as default
    var currmon = new Date(year,month),
        nextmon = new Date(year,month+1); // no need to check for December overflow - JS does this automatically
    return Math.floor((nextmon.getTime()-currmon.getTime())/24*3600);
}
```

This should be enough to get you on the right track. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: I think this is a bit misleading. There's no such thing as "difference in months". A month isn't a timespan.

Comment: I'm 20 years and one month old. How is a month not a timespan in this context, which is the context the OP was asking about? "I want to calculate time elapsed since my birthday..."

Comment: If today is 25th of march, what date was 1 month ago? Was it 31 days or 29 days ago? I have no idea.

Comment: 29 days, obviously, as "1 month ago" is 25th of February. Asking what one month ago from 31st of March is a little more complicated, though, but by the time the algorithm gets that far the date itself is somewhat abstracted.

Comment: The 31st of March example shows that whatever rule you choose, you'll end up hitting inconsistencies and edge cases raising from the fact that a month can mean isn't a fixed timespan.

Comment: And note that the OP is asking for the reverse: you get a timespan and want to say, for instance, how many months are in it. Best you can do is count starts of months, or ends of months.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getDaysInMonth(month,year) {     
    if( typeof year == "undefined") year = 1999; // any non-leap-year works as default     
    var currmon = new Date(year,month),     
        nextmon = new Date(year,month+1);
    return Math.floor((nextmon.getTime()-currmon.getTime())/(24*3600*1000));
} 
function getDateTimeSince(target) { // target should be a Date object
    var now = new Date(), yd, md, dd, hd, nd, sd, out = []; 

    yd = now.getFullYear()-target.getFullYear();
    md = now.getMonth()-target.getMonth();
    dd = now.getDate()-target.getDate();
    hd = now.getHours()-target.getHours();
    nd = now.getMinutes()-target.getMinutes();
    sd = now.getSeconds()-target.getSeconds(); 

    if( md < 0) {yd--; md += 12;}
    if( dd < 0) {
        md--;
        dd += getDaysInMonth(now.getMonth()-1,now.getFullYear());
    }
    if( hd < 0) {dd--; hd += 24;}
    if( nd < 0) {hd--; nd += 60;}
    if( sd < 0) {nd--; sd += 60;}

    if( yd > 0) out.push( yd+" year"+(yd == 1 ? "" : "s"));
    if( md > 0) out.push( md+" month"+(md == 1 ? "" : "s"));
    if( dd > 0) out.push( dd+" day"+(dd == 1 ? "" : "s"));
    if( hd > 0) out.push( hd+" hour"+(hd == 1 ? "" : "s"));
    if( nd > 0) out.push( nd+" minute"+(nd == 1 ? "" : "s"));
    if( sd > 0) out.push( sd+" second"+(sd == 1 ? "" : "s"));
    return out.join(" ");
}
```

This is a different version of Kolink's Code. There were a number of errors in his that stopped this script from working correctly...

Comment: Warning: this code continues to be broken - it doesn't handle minute boundary for second calculations, and hour boundary for minute calculations and so on. For example, lets say it is now 11:31:05  (11:31am and 5sec) and we call it with 11:30:55, it will say that elapsed time is 1min 10sec, whereas in fact the difference between these two timestamps is: 10sec.

Comment: For my purpouses (finding how many days and hours have passed since yesterday) it worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way to calculate elapsed time.

1. Calculate difference between origin date and today in milliseconds
2. Pass this difference to a Date object called result
3. Remember from Date Object definition that that result object is milliseconds from 01/01/1970 00:00:00.
4. Inspect this result object to get Years, Months, and so on.

Here is the code to do so.

```
Date.prototype.getElapsedTime = function() {
  var diffDate = new Date(Date.now() - this);
  return "Elapsed Time: Years: " + (diffDate.getFullYear() - 1970) + ", Months: " + diffDate.getMonth() + ", Days: " + (diffDate.getDate() - 1) + ", Hours: " + diffDate.getHours() + ", Minutes: " + diffDate.getMinutes() + ", Seconds: " + diffDate.getSeconds();
};

var from = new Date("01/08/1986 04:07:00");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = from.getElapsedTime();
```

Here is something you can play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/nishchal/u8gt2gwq/4/

Answer (score 0):

I like this one:

```
function lifeSpan(t0) {var x=new Date()-t0, a=x, i=0,s=0,m=0,h=0,j=0;
  if(a>=1){i=a%1000;a=(a-i)/1000;
  if(a>=1){s=a%60;a=(a-s)/60;
  if(a>=1){m=a%60;a=(a-m)/60;
  if(a>=1){h=a%24;a=(a-h)/24;
  if(a>=1){j=a;//...
  }}}}}
  return 'Elapsed: '+i+'ms '+s+'s '+m+'mn '+h+'h '+j+'j (or '+x+'ms).';}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick algorithm for displaying time elapsed since a unix/epoch timestamp:

```js
const showElapsedTime = (timestamp) => {
    if (typeof timestamp !== 'number') return 'NaN'        

    const SECOND = 1000
    const MINUTE = 1000 * 60
    const HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60
    const DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    const MONTH = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
    const YEAR = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12
    
    const elapsed = ((new Date()).valueOf() - timestamp)
    
    if (elapsed <= MINUTE) return `${Math.round(elapsed / SECOND)}s`
    if (elapsed <= HOUR) return `${Math.round(elapsed / MINUTE)}m`
    if (elapsed <= DAY) return `${Math.round(elapsed / HOUR)}h`
    if (elapsed <= MONTH) return `${Math.round(elapsed / DAY)}d`
    if (elapsed <= YEAR) return `${Math.round(elapsed / MONTH)}mo`
    return `${Math.round(elapsed / YEAR)}y`
}
      
const createdAt = 1541301301000

console.log(showElapsedTime(createdAt + 5000000))
console.log(showElapsedTime(createdAt))
console.log(showElapsedTime(createdAt - 500000000))
```

`(new Date()).valueOf()` returns the number of seconds elapsed since Jan 1, 1970.

After you get that, you just need the timestamp of your event, and you can subtract it from the current time. This leaves the number of seconds elapsed, which can be converted into a human readable format by dividing by the correct number of units.

For example, 3000 milliseconds is 300 seconds. The algorithm I showed works with millisecond timestamps (divide everything by 1000 for seconds), so in the algorithm, 3000 would be be greater than `MINUTE` but less than `HOUR`, so it would return `3000 / MINUTE` and return `3s`.

This algorithm is useful if you are displaying a card, such as a job posting that was posted `2d ago`.

I didn't like most of the other answers I found because they were not simple enough or readable enough. I hope my answer is quickly understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple algorithm for finding the elapse time:

```js
  time_elapsed_string = function(ptime){
    var etime = (Date.now() / 1000 | 0 ) - ptime;

    if (etime < 1)
    {
      return '0 seconds';
    }

    var a = {'31536000' :  'year',
              '2592000'  :  'month',
              '86400' :  'day',
              '3600' :  'hour',
              '60'  :  'minute',
              '1'  :  'second'
            };
    var a_plural = { 'year'   : 'years',
                      'month'  : 'months',
                      'day'    : 'days',
                      'hour'   : 'hours',
                      'minute' : 'minutes',
                      'second' : 'seconds'
                    };
    var output = '';
    $.each(a,function(secs,str){
        var d = etime / secs;
        if (d >= 1){
          var r = Math.round(d);
          output = r + ' ' + (r > 1 ? a_plural[str] : str) + ' ago';
          return true;
        }
    });
    return output;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following:

```
let getTimeElpasedString = (datetime, depth=1 )=>{
    /*
        depth = 0 means start at milliseconds
        depth = 1 means start at seconds
        ...
    */
    datetime = Date.parse(datetime).getElapsed()
    console.log(datetime)
    let dividers = [1000, 60, 60, 24, 7]
    let str = ''
    let units = ["milliseconds", "seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days"]
    let reminders = []
    dividers.forEach(d=>{
        reminders.push(datetime % d)
        datetime = parseInt(datetime/d) 
    })
    reminders = reminders.slice(depth).reverse()
    units = units.slice(depth).reverse()
    for(let i=0; i<reminders.length; i++){
        // skip which is equal to zero
        if(reminders[i] != 0)
            str += `${reminders[i]} ${units[i]} `
    }
    return str + "ago"
}
```